GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker AuthorizeAsyncCore on iOS (IPhone) from Middleware .net Core Web API
I'm using a solution involving similar code to that which is explained here: How do I set return_uri for GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync?
What I've discovered after getting the code to work is that from the .NET Core Web API; the authenticate method opens a browser rather than sending the google authentication display to the iOS device. Obviously, this poses a bit of an issue :).
I'm sure it is the newness I have to developing with this in a pseudo-middleware scenario but I'm hoping someone else has run into this case and can help me understand what I'm doing incorrectly.
Visual Studio Project includes the following:
-- Note: There is no project reference between the two by design.
.NET 9 Maui Application Project - "MAUIAPP"  --
.NET 9 Core Web API Project - "LogonAPI"  -- Runs on a port on "http:LocalHost"
Using ngrok.exe to tunnel from https url provided by them which points to the development machine's local http port -- this is all working successfully.
I am deploying to a connected iOS(Iphone) connected to my development machine to which the MAUIAPP is being deployed successfully.  I have a button on the main page which calls a service in the MAUIAPP "LogonService.cs" and a function "LogonGoogle".
The button points to the url on my localhost port running the .net core web api in debug mode and onclick successfully instantiates and calls the rest api in the controller:
[HttpGet("/GoogleAuth/Authenticate")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate()
{
    try
    {
        string[] Scopes = { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" };             
        //requires full scope to get ACL list..
        UserCredential credential;
        string ApplicationName = "HairTriggerProd3";
        //just reference the namespaces in your using block

        using (var stream = new FileStream
                            (
                            "googleSecrets.json",
                            FileMode.Open, 
                            FileAccess.Read
                            )
              )
        {

            // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is 
            // created
            // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.

            string credPath = "googleSecretsRefresh";
            credential = dsAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }

        return Ok(credential);
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        return BadRequest(x);
    }
}

public class dsAuthorizationBroker : GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker
{
    public static string RedirectUri = "https:[provided ngrok tunnel]/ReturnFromGoogle";

    public new static async Task<UserCredential> AuthorizeAsync(
        ClientSecrets clientSecrets,
        IEnumerable<string> scopes,
        string user,
        CancellationToken taskCancellationToken,
        IDataStore dataStore = null)
    {
        var initializer = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
        {
            ClientSecrets = clientSecrets,
        };
        return await AuthorizeAsyncCore(initializer, scopes, user,
            taskCancellationToken, dataStore).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private static async Task<UserCredential> AuthorizeAsyncCore(
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer initializer,
        IEnumerable<string> scopes,
        string user,
        CancellationToken taskCancellationToken,
        IDataStore dataStore)
    {
        initializer.Scopes = scopes;
        initializer.DataStore = dataStore ?? new FileDataStore(Folder);
        var flow = new dsAuthorizationCodeFlow(initializer);
        return await new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow,
            new LocalServerCodeReceiver())
            .AuthorizeAsync(user, taskCancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}


public class dsAuthorizationCodeFlow : GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
{
    public dsAuthorizationCodeFlow(Initializer initializer)
        : base(initializer) { }

    public override AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl
                   CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest(string redirectUri)
    {
        return base.CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest(dsAuthorizationBroker.RedirectUri);
    }
}


When the invocation of the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker's AuthorizeAsync(... is called the web api opens the google challenge in a browser window on my development machine rather than on the device and as such the user will not see the challenge to select or enter credentials.
Can anyone help a newbie here with this issue and tell me how I make sure the device is what receives the challenge?
